# Should RSS link tag point to home page, or specific page RSS channel references?

Tags: rss

I think I know the answer, but wanted to double check:

Should the link tag in an RSS feed always point to a website's home page or to the most relevant page?

What I mean: say there is a website devoted to real estate (http://www.realestate.com) that has multiple RSS feeds. One RSS feed is latest listings, one RSS feed is latest home listings, one RSS feed is latest apartment listings, etc. The home listings can be found at http://www.realestate.com/home-listings.html. The apartment listings can be found at http://www.realestate.com/apartment-listings.html

Should the link tag for all 3 RSS feeds point to http://www.realestate.com/? Or should it point to, respectively, http://www.realestate.com/, http://www.realestate.com/home-listings.html and http://www.realestate.com/appartment-listings.html?

Answer (score 0):

The RSS "Profile" states that "The link element identifies the URL of the web site associated with the feed (required)."
http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-link

But let's be pragamtic. The intention here, is certainly to let the user click on the link to go to the source of information.

I think it would be better to link to the apropriate section than to the homepage.